# after adding vuex to main.js components don't render

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vuex

My apologies with this dumb question. I'm new to Vue and followed some tutorial on just setting it up and did it the way advised but now I don't see anything.

As said above, after importing and adding Vuex to my project, nothing is loaded on the page and there are no errors in the terminal while running the development server.

#### main.js

```js
// ** if I comment these out then the page will load
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store/store.js' // <-- **

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store, // <-- **
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

#### store.js

```js
import Vue from "vue"
import Vuex from "vuex"

Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.store({
  state: {
    user: '',
    role: ''
  },
  mutations: {
  },
  actions: {
  },
  getters: {
  }
})
```

if there is additional information needed then let me know

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted, must be somewhere else. Do you get any errors?

Comment: crap I do.... I missed it I was looking at the wrong screen... I'll update the question if I don't find the solution after googling error

Comment: another good place to look for errors is the browser developer tools console

Comment: yea I am a backend developer. not used to the browser haha thanks